# Must a Bicyclist Riding on a Sidewalk Stop at a Stop Sign?

Tags: legal, california

Riding my bicycle legally on the sidewalk, I approach an intersection controlled by a stop sign. Let's say there are wheelchair ramps at the intersection, and there may or may not be painted pedestrian crosswalk lines. Must I make a full stop before crossing the side street?

My question pertains to California law but I realize that the answer may differ in other jurisdictions. Also, it may make a difference whether or not there are painted crosswalk lines, and whether the road is to my left or to my right.

The strategy, if legal, may be useful to bicyclists who may avoid having to make a full stop by riding on the sidewalk shortly before reaching the intersection.

Another situation is a 3 way intersection with 3 stop signs where I am not crossing a side street. If I am on the street, I know I must stop, but I am quite confident that I am not required to stop if I am on the sidewalk.

As a side issue, it does appear that it is legal for me to ride on the sidewalk in California with the road to my right and continue to ride between the crosswalk lines across an intersecting street. California law treats the crosswalk as an extension of the sidewalk, thus giving me the same rights that I have on the sidewalk.

Comment: Whether or not you're required to by law, I'd say it's a good idea to stop even if you're on the sidewalk. And a better idea to simply ride in the street.

Comment: Also, many counties and local municipalities in California  ban riding on sidewalks. Check your local laws if you really insist on doing so.

Comment: While I think it is an odd question, at best, why don't you at least tell us the jurisdiction you are biking in.

Comment: Probably the only thing less safe than riding on the sidewalks is riding on the roads and then hopping over to the sidewalk near every corner so you can "legally" ignore the stop sign.

Comment: It's possible you may not be required to come to a "full stop", but you must at least slow to a "walk" (not a "trot") so that you're proceeding at the pace of a pedestrian, not a cyclist.  It's unreasonable to expect motorists to expect cyclists to come darting across an intersection in a crosswalk, vs moving slowly towards and into the intersection as a person on foot would.

Comment: If you were going for a jog, would you just jog through the intersection? or would you slow down a bit to make sure that there wasn't any cars coming?  I guess it depends on the corner, and how far up the intersection road you can see.  If you can see far enough up the road to ensure that there won't be any cars, it's probably OK to continue straight on through (assuming it's legal to begin with), but if you can't see the car coming, don't assume they'll stop for the stop sign either.

Comment: [Look both ways, twice, before you enter the intersection (and if you see a policeman, then come to a complete stop)](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/stop/)

Comment: I never intended to advocate unsafe cycling. I think ChrisW's advice says it best. Idaho's traffic laws allow bicyclists to legally treat stop signs as yield signs, which is the way most cyclists behave anyway. See http://blogs.bicycling.com/blogs/roadrights/2009/09/01/making-better-laws/  Bicyclists have excellent visibility and normally can spot police cars in time to stop. Legal or not, I would not advocate using a sidewalk in known view of cops. I was planning to use the approach where motorcycle cops are known to hide and watch intersections, but safety considerations changed my mind.

Answer (score 14):

According to the state's [site](http://www.chp.ca.gov/html/bicycleriding.html) about bicycles, there are only laws against riding on sidewalks for certain locales. Otherwise, similar to most states, you are governed as a pedestrian when riding on the sidewalk. That means if you dart in front of traffic unexpectedly, even in a crosswalk, you can still be at fault.

However, you should ALWAYS stop at an intersection, regardless of whether you are a pedestrian or a vehicle. It's polite and it's a heck of a lot safer than assuming the coast is clear. And don't be that guy who rides on sidewalks just to avoid traffic laws and stop signs, nobody likes that.

Comment: More importantly, you shouldn't be riding on the sidewalks anyway. Established consensus is that it's significantly more dangerous than riding on the road.

Comment: Consensus and statistical evidence.

Comment: _"at an intersection"_ Meaning a stop-sign intersection? Might want to edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on local rules. In Latvia (Europe) a road sign is not applicable to you if it is located on the left of your path. Also, bicycle rules are not clear enough yet, so sometimes it is a grey area.

Answer (score 0):

Realize its been a decade but I had the same question. His question is about legality, not whether it is a "good idea." As a daily rider, there are dozens of streets that I cross where you can see a 1/4 mile in every direction and it is clearly "safe" to do this. If a pedestrian does not have to stop walking/jogging at a stop sign when coming to a crosswalk, then the same rule applies if you establish yourself as using the sidewalk prior to entering the crosswalk. It is legal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Since you are revisiting an older question, you might take this opportunity to provide updated information on the laws governing cycling in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

In Switzerland, cyclists are likely expected to respect the STOP sign, because some can be found on the shared pedestrian/bicycle roads. Cars, motorbikes and even mopeds are not permitted on these roads, so who is supposed to read the sign
and also road marking? Could not be just for pedestrians.

[image]

If valid in one place, the sign should be valid in another as well. Track stand.